# Toggle variable value based on another variable in variables.yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I have a below variables.yml file

```
variables:
  vmImage: ubuntu
  poolName: 'cloud'
  env: Dev
  module: $(moduleName)
  
  sc: abc-dev
  rg: abc-dev-rg
  location: eus2
```

I would like to toggle the value of sc,rg and location based on the value of $(moduleName). Is this possible to achieve.

something like this

```
- ${if eq($(modulename), 'abc') }: 
    sc: abc-dev
    rg: abc-dev-rg
    location: eus2
- ${if eq($(modulename), 'xyz') }: 
    sc: xyz-dev
    rg: xyz-dev-rg
    location: scus
```

I tried using multiple if conditions but looks like this cannot be done is variables.yml file. So I  was looking for any alternative options.

Comment: Hi @PKP, have you checked the suggestions below? Currently, it doesn't support assigning values to variables in variable template. As workarounds, you can select the corresponding variable template based on the value of `moduleName` as mentioned in my answer. Or you can define your variables directly in the main yaml as mentioned by wenbo.

Answer (score 0):

variables.yml

```
variables:
  vmImage: ubuntu
  poolName: 'cloud'
  env: Dev
  module: 'xyz'
```

main.yml

```
variables:
- template: variables.yml

- ${{ if eq('1', '1') }}:
  - name: sc1
    value: abc-dev1
  - name: rg1
    value: abc-dev-rg1
  - name: location1
    value: eus21

- ${{ if eq(variables.module, 'abc') }}:
  - name: sc
    value: abc-dev
  - name: rg
    value: abc-dev-rg
  - name: location
    value: eus2
- ${{ if eq(variables.module, 'xyz') }}:
  - name: sc
    value: xyz-dev
  - name: rg
    value: xyz-dev-rg
  - name: location
    value: scus

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables.sc, 'abc-dev') }}:
  - script: echo "this is $(sc)"
- ${{ elseif eq(variables.sc, 'xyz-dev') }}: # true
  - script: echo "this is $(sc)" 
- ${{ else }}:
  - script: echo "this is nothing"

- script: echo "$(sc1)"
```

change the module value in variables, you should get the corresponding result. hope this can help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, we cannot use condition to assign values to variables in variable template.

As a workaround, you can create a variable template for each moduleName and then select the corresponding template based on the value of moduleName. For example, create variable templates "abc-var.yml" and "xyz-var.yml".

xyz-var.yml:

```
variables:
  vmImage: ubuntu
  poolName: 'cloud'
  env: Dev
  module: 'xyz'
  sc: xyz-dev
  rg: xyz-dev-rg
  location: scus
```

In the main yaml, define `modulename` as parameter and select template based on the value of `modulename`.

```
parameters:
- name: modulename
  type: string
  default: "abc"
  values:
  - abc
  - xyz
variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.modulename, 'abc') }}:
  - template: 'abc-var.yml'
- ${{ if eq(parameters.modulename, 'xyz') }}:
  - template: 'xyz-var.yml'
```

When you run the pipeline, you can select the value of `modulename` from UI.
[image]